# UITableView Header Gap and Resizing Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder

I have two questions related to UITableViews.

1) The first one is, what is the gap at the top of the UITableView? My app always starts with the top cell not flush with the top of the tableview (as shown in the second image), it starts about one cell lower, i.e. where that gap is in the interface builder. I can't find where that is coming from, or why.

2) I can't seem to resize the uitableview programmatically, I'm trying to reduce the height after a popup appears. I've shown an example of it not working in the second picture.

Here is (an example of) what I am trying at the moment:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.table_view.delegate = self;

    CGRect tableBounds = self.table_view.bounds;
    tableBounds.size.height -= 100;
    self.table_view.bounds = tableBounds;

    CGRect tableFrame = self.table_view.frame;
    tableBounds.size.height -= 100;
    self.table_view.frame = tableFrame;
}
```

Thanks!

UITableView Selected:

[image: Table View]

Simulation:

[image: Simulation]

Comment: Turn off auto layout and see if it works ! If it does you might wanna re think your constraints .

Answer (score 0):

In your xib (or storyboard) put your UITableView at position (0,0). ( the same position as the navigation bar).

Answer (score 0):

The first image shows that your table view has problems even in Interface Builder. It looks as if you've set the top inset incorrectly; check your edge insets.

The reason your resizing code is not working is probably that it is too early (`viewDidLoad`); put it in `viewDidAppear:` and see if that works, and if it does, try moving it back to `viewWillAppear:` so the user doesn't see the resizing. If it doesn't work, it might be because you're using auto layout; you can't manually alter the frame of something whose frame is dictated by auto layout. (Your resizing code is also silly; you want to set the frame, not the bounds.) But it might also be because you're using a UITableViewController in a UINavigationController; if you do that, the table view is under the navigation controller's direct control and its size is not up to you.